# Show Fourier series can be rearranged to equal a series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

I'm stuck trying to solve this problem: Let $f \in C(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z};\mathbb{C})$ and define the trigonometric Fourier coefficients $a_n,b_n$ for $n=0,1,2,3,...$ by $$a_n=2\int_0^1f(x)\cos(2\pi nx)dx, b_n=2\int_0^1f(x)\sin(2\pi nx)dx.$$ Show that the Fourier series of $f, \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\hat{f}(n)e_n$, can be rearranged to equal the series $$\frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum^\infty_{n=1}(a_n\cos(2\pi nx)+b_n\sin(2\pi nx)).$$

So far I have
$$\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}\hat{f}(n),e_n$$
$$=\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}\int_0^1f(x)e^{-2\pi inx}dxe_n$$
$$= 2\sum^\infty_{n=1} [\int_0^1f(x)\cos(2\pi nx)dx-i\int_0^1f(x)\sin(2\pi nx)dx](\cos(2\pi nx)+i\sin(2\pi nx)$$
$$= 2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\cos(2\pi nx)\int_0^1f(x)\cos(2\pi nx)dx+\sin(2\pi nx)\int_0^1f(x)\sin(2\pi nx)dx+i\sin(2\pi nx)\int_0^1f(x)\cos(2\pi nx)dx-i\cos(2\pi nx)\int_0^1f(x)\sin(2\pi nx)dx$$
$$= \sum^\infty_{n=1}[a_n\cos(2\pi nx)+b_n\sin(2\pi nx)]+2i\sin(2\pi nx)\int_0^1f(x)\cos(2\pi nx)dx-2i\cos(2\pi nx)\int_0^1f(x)\sin(2\pi nx)dx$$

But I can't get the last piece to simplify.

Comment: Expansion is confusing.  Missing dx?  (My ignorance) $e_n$ =? ?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to clear it up a bit using brackets instead of parentheses. $e_n$
 should be equal to $\cos(2\pi nx)+i\sin(2\pi nx)=e^{-2\pi nx}$ I believe

Comment: $f(x)e^{-2\pi inx}dxe_n$ looks funny.

Comment: Using x in two different contexts - dummy in integral and real for $e_n$ can be confusing.  Change dummy to a different letter.